# Remember touchpad state after reboot

Tags: touchpad

I usually use an external pointing device with my laptop and the first thing I do upon logging into the laptop is to press the laptop's function key to disable the touchpad.

I seem to recall previous versions of Ubuntu saving the touchpad state across shutdowns/reboots.

I would like the state of the touchpad to remain until I change it again using the laptop's enable/disable touchpad function key.

Is there a way to accomplish this using the existing laptop function key?

My laptop is a Lenovo IdeaPad Y510P and Fn-F6 is it's Disable/Enable touchpad button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to go to settings --> mouse and touchpad then select your touchpad and take the check mark out of enable this device

Comment: This works good, but I wish it could be tied to the laptop's hardware function key.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: In that case you might want to check the BIOS of the computer for a setting to disable/enable the touchpad.